# Iterating test case in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a test case and i have to iterate the test case no.of times.is there any way we can iterate the test case?

````
Signin-Personal-Account
[Tags]  Tvh2
    Given Number of users signs in to their respective devices  ${xyz}
    Then xyz sees that Sign in is successful
    When xyz signs out from the device
    Then xyz sees that sign out was successful   
    And Signin is repeated for 5 times for Ellie```
````

Test has to repeat 5 times. how to make test case iterate no.of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using for loop:

```
*** Test cases ***
Multiple sign in test
    :FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE   5
    \    Signin-Personal-Account 

*** Keywords ***
Signin-Personal-Account
    [Tags]  Tvh2
    Given Number of users signs in to their respective devices  ${xyz}
    Then xyz sees that Sign in is successful
    When xyz signs out from the device
    Then xyz sees that sign out was successful
```

Make sure to check the syntax for `FOR` loop based on the version of robot framework you are using - [FOR loop syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#for-loops)

Comment: @sameem-  i used the same logic but after first time it got signed in, second time it is not able to sign in, i am getting an error like - ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))

Comment: i used repet keyword also. is there any other work around to resolve this one